# How to add functionality to React native splash screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

I am using react-native-splash-screen and got it working even with face id which is cool. my problem is now I want to add some functionality to the splash screen. I see when Monzo (for example) there app loads, if you click off the face id then some different text appears behind it. but considering splash/launch screens are now written inside xcode, how does one add JS functionality to render something on that screen depending on users actions?

Comment: not possible with react native.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial really?! how do react native folk achieve this then?

Comment: react-native-splash-screen is static. You can of course render a different component after you turn off react-splash-screen to show whatever you want.